# Grid card layout does not work properly in my project

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am currently trying to create a grid-layout with HTML/CSS. I have the following code

```
<section class="home-d ">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="l-heading py-3">hot news</h2>
    <div class="articles-container">
      <!-- Article 1 -->
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-1-img@1X(2).png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 2 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-2-img@1X(1).png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 3 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-3-img@1X(1).png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Western Pyramid Resort in Egypt</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 4 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-4-img@1X(2).png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Grand Meadows Resort in Maldives</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 5 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-5-img.png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Wanderlust Resort in Tenerife</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 6 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-6-img@1X(1).png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Twin Sanctuary Hotel in Great Britain</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 7 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-7-img@1X.png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>Prism Hotel in Ireland</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Article 8 -->
      </article>
      <article class="card">
        <img src="./img/hot-news-img/post-8-img@1X.png" alt="" />
        <div class="article-content">
          <h3>King's Shroud Resort in Spain</h3>
          <p>
            Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
            cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
            and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
            Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
            with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
            great way to decorate your outdoor
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
  .container {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

  .home-d {

      text-align: center;

   }

  .home-d .articles-container{

      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;

   }

  .home-d .articles-container>*:first-child,
  .home-d .articles-container>*:first-child {

      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 1rem;
      align-items: center;
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;

  }


  .home-d .articles-container>*:last-child {
      grid-column: 2 / span 2;

   }

  .card{
      border:1px solid #3333;

   }
```

Here is link https://jsfiddle.net/familagash/dfvhrxq5/ .
It looks like this when running the code.
But i would like to make like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2mpQ.jpg)

I searched however i couldn't find it. İt has a lot of grid cards example but I couldn't find any sample to do it. Who can help me?

Comment: Try looking into Masonry grid types: see the last example on the Bootstrap card page (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/).

Comment: The problem here is that your suggested layout is clearly not just 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

Suggestion: It is better to use background rather than image in this case.

```css
.home-d { text-align: center; }
  .home-d .articles-container { padding: 15px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 70% 30%; grid-gap: 15px; text-align: center; }
  .home-d .articles-container.equal { grid-template-columns: repeat(2,50%); }
  .side-by-side { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2,50%); align-items: center;}
  .home-d .articles-container:last-child { grid-template-columns: 30% 70%; }
  .home-d .articles-container img { width: 100%; }
  .card { background: #f9f9f9; }
  .side-by-side .article-content { padding: 15px; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<section class="home-d ">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="l-heading py-3">hot news</h2>
        <div class="articles-container">
          <!-- Article 1 -->
          <article class="card side-by-side"><!-- added class -->
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DpqKJJK/latest-post-4-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-4-img-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 2 -->
          </article>
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/khd8mFv/latest-post-3-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-3-img-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 3 -->
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="articles-container equal"> <!-- added class -->
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/khd8mFv/latest-post-3-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-3-img-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Western Pyramid Resort in Egypt</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 4 -->
          </article>
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SJMzkLV/latest-post-6-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-6-img-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Grand Meadows Resort in Maldives</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 5 -->
          </article>
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SJMzkLV/latest-post-6-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-6-img-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Wanderlust Resort in Tenerife</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 6 -->
          </article>
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/41rKvWn/Layer-22-1-X.png" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Twin Sanctuary Hotel in Great Britain</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 7 -->
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="articles-container">          
          <article class="card">
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/41rKvWn/Layer-22-1-X.png" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>Prism Hotel in Ireland</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 8 -->
          </article>
          <article class="card side-by-side"><!-- added class -->
            <a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/41rKvWn/Layer-22-1-X.png" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0"></a>
            <div class="article-content">
              <h3>King's Shroud Resort in Spain</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. That was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix your html structure to make things easier to layout. I also use SCSS and some advanced technique, you can check the code bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,600,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="home-d ">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="news__heading">hot news</h2>
      <div class="articles-container">
        <div class="article__section-1">
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="https://www.offpeakluxury.com/db_library/matfen-hall-hotel/1024x768_8QWAR_11332img-16876-1.jpg" alt="latest-post-4-img-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/khd8mFv/latest-post-3-img-1-X.png" alt="latest-post-3-img-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Prophecy Hotel & Spa in Emirate</h3>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="article__section-2">
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="http://www.bellamarhotel.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/386/files/photogallery-hotel/emsa_b_62.jpg" alt="latest-post-3-img-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Western Pyramid Resort in Egypt</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 4 -->
          </article>
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="http://www.bellamarhotel.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/386/files/photogallery-hotel/emsa_b_62.jpg" alt="latest-post-6-img-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Grand Meadows Resort in Maldives</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 5 -->
          </article>
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="http://www.atlanticahotels.com/userthumbs/reservation/64773c28-ae74-46f9-b52a-940cc548d4ca/hotelimages/thumbs_1920x/aphrodite-hills-hotel-by-atlantica-deluxe-room-swim-up.jpg" alt="latest-post-6-img-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Wanderlust Resort in Tenerife</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 6 -->
          </article>
          <article class="article__card">
            <img src="http://www.atlanticahotels.com/userthumbs/reservation/64773c28-ae74-46f9-b52a-940cc548d4ca/hotelimages/thumbs_1920x/aphrodite-hills-hotel-by-atlantica-deluxe-room-swim-up.jpg" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0">
            <div class="article__content">
              <h3>Twin Sanctuary Hotel in Great Britain</h3>
              <p>
                Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
                cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
                and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
                Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
                with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
                great way to decorate your outdoor
              </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Article 7 -->
          </article>

        </div>
        <article class="article__card">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/41rKvWn/Layer-22-1-X.png" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0">
          <div class="article-content">
            <h3>Prism Hotel in Ireland</h3>
          </div>
          <!-- Article 8 -->
        </article>
        <article class="article__card">
          <a href="https://imgbb.com/"></a><img src="https://i.ibb.co/41rKvWn/Layer-22-1-X.png" alt="Layer-22-1-X" border="0"></a>
          <div class="article-content">
            <h3>King's Shroud Resort in Spain</h3>
            <p>
              Amazing Gabion Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or
              cylinder filled with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil
              and It is a great way to decorate your outdoor. Amazing Gabion
              Ideas for Outdoors A Gabion is a cage box or cylinder filled
              with rocks, concrete, or sometimes sand and soil and It is a
              great way to decorate your outdoor
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>

*,*::after, *::before{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333333;
}

.container{
  text-align: center;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.news{
  &__heading{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(0, 169, 236);
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 3rem;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

.article{
  &__section-1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 3rem;

    .article{
      &__card{
        display: flex;
        text-align: right;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 1rem;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;

        &:first-child {
          grid-column: 1/4;
          img{
            height: 19rem;
            object-fit: cover;
            // width: 25rem;
          }
        }

        &:last-child{
          flex-direction: column;
          img{
            // height: 10rem;
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
      }
      &__content{
        padding: 2rem;
      }
    }
  }

  &__section-2{
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-gap: 4.5rem;

    .article{
      &__card {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        img{
          width: 100%;;
        }
      }

      &__content {
        padding: 2rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use watch sass plugin in vscode to compile sass code

Comment: Good solution. But i don't have properly experience about Scss. However it will be valuable for my next step.

Comment: Sass can make your css code become more elegant, and easy to read.